# PHP + Curl Post. It fills the form, but does not post

Tags: php, post, curl

My code

```
<?php

$url='Search.jsp';
// disguises the curl using fake headers and a fake user agent. 
function disguise_curl($url) 
{ 
  $curl = curl_init(); 

  // Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6 
  // below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. :/ 
  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 


  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk/protected/wca/publicRegisterVehicleSearch.jsp'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'search.licenceTypeID=34&search.licenceLinkFileID=2&search.vehicleRegNumber=5&publicRegisterVehicle=Search');
  $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command 
  echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($curl); // close the connection 
  return $html; // and finally, return $html 
} 

// uses the function and displays the text off the website 
$text = disguise_curl($url); 
echo $text; 
?>
```

It returns the page, with the form filled, but it does not post it. The curl_getinfo response I get is..

> 200HTTP/1.1 200 OK Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control:
>   no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00
>   GMT Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Language: en-GB
>   Content-Length: 5901 Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2012 12:24:08 GMT Server:
>   Apache

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems your code is correct, so you should make sure the fields you request are right, the respond with status 200 shows your request is right, but might your field is incorrect, you can write a test page on server and use above code to test.

Comment: Does the status 200 code show that the form was posted though? Or would it not respond with that information? The form has two submit buttons, and I specified one by saying 'publicRegisterVehicle=Search', is that correct?

Comment: There are 2 hidden form fields on the page that might need to be set. _sourcePage and __fp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you'll probably want to do, firstly I believe it works better across different operating systems if you supply an absolute path to the cookiejar:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");
```

Also, you can have the script visit the homepage first to grab the session cookie:

```
disguise_curl("https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk");
```

Then you can post the form to `https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk/protected/actions/PublicRegister.action` (make sure cookies.txt exists):

```
<?php

// disguises the curl using fake headers and a fake user agent. 
function disguise_curl($url, $post = false) 
{ 
  $curl = curl_init(); 

  // Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6 
  // below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. :/ 
  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 


  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk/protected/wca/publicRegisterVehicleSearch.jsp'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  if ($post)
  {
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'search.licenceTypeID=34&search.licenceLinkFileID=2&search.vehicleRegNumber=5&publicRegisterVehicle=Search');
  }
  $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command 
  //echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($curl); // close the connection 
  return $html; // and finally, return $html 
} 

// Visit the home-page first to get the session cookie
disguise_curl("https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk"); 

// uses the function and displays the text off the website 

$url = 'https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk/protected/actions/PublicRegister.action';

$text = disguise_curl($url, true); 
echo $text; 
?>
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When opening https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk/protected/wca/publicRegisterVehicleSearch.jsp with my browser, I'm redirected to https://lalpacweb.blackpool.gov.uk/sessiontimeout.jsp and presented with a "Session Timeout" error. Maybe you must make two requests. One to login (and possibly obtain the session cookie) and one to actually perform the search. curl should automatically send cookies it has received in previous requests within the same session. Otherwise set it `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'CookieName=CookieValue');`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. After doing some more research myself, I've discovered that if I go to the URL manually, make a post, I then get a jsessionID cookie. Now when I update my cookies.txt with that jsessionID, my script works and it loads the page. However, it only seems to load the info from the time that session was made. It appears that when my script posts the form, it saves a jsessionID but the ones created on my site are invalid and don't work. However, if I use the one created on the native site itself and update my cookies.txt, it works.

Comment: Problem is though, that sessionID expires after 10 minutes. So I'd have to keep going to that website, posting the form, getting a session ID, and then updating my cookies.txt file. Any idea why, when posting the form via curl, the sessionID that's created doesn't work. It updates the cookies.txt, and does create a session, but it doesn't mean anything to the server. But I don't see why not - the server thinks the referring page is itself, and that it's a regular request.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post =  urlencode('search.licenceTypeID=34&search.licenceLinkFileID=2&search.vehicleRegNumber=5&publicRegisterVehicle=Search');
```

**or**

```
$post = array(
'search.licenceTypeID' => 34,
'search.licenceLinkFileID' => 2,
'search.vehicleRegNumber' => 5,
'publicRegisterVehicle' => 'Search'
)


curl_setopt ($init, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```